# ¿Cómo cambiar el punto decimal por comma en Sequelize?

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

He conseguido que los números se formateen correctamente, pero en formato de punto decimal, y necesito que sea coma.

Con este código aplico el formato:

```
.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');
```

Y este es el resultado:

**1,000.00**

Busco que sea este:

**1.000,00**

Se agradecen los comentarios.

**ACTUALIZACION**

La DB se crea en el portal Heroku.

Este es el código para abrir la DB:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(DB_name, user, pwd,                   
      { dialect:  protocol,
        protocol: protocol,
        port:     port,
        host:     host,
        storage:  storage,                                              
        omitNull: true                                                        }
    );
```

Comment: ¿Buscas que se haga directamente en la base de datos o del lado cliente? ¿Qué base de datos estás usando?

Comment: Creo que sería mejor en la base de datos para que todo tenga ese formato. Uso postgreSQL.

Comment: ¿Ya has intentado hacer un insert usando esa notación? ¿La cambia Sequelize por la notación US? PostgreSQL no tiene problema en manejar diversos formatos de números si está bien configurada la base de datos (collation/charset).

Comment: No acepta insert con coma decimal. He intentado configurar collate en la creación de la DB, pero no consigo el formato. ¿Crees que sería mejor hacerlo en el lado cliente?